# Avoid the default value if more than one exist or select the existing single value in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select

In my website, I have a product image display region. When a user click on a product, it will redirect to the image display page. I had set a default image. Which will display when user see the product. But when the user go to the product image page, I don't want to show the default image, if there exist more than one image. But I need to show the default image if there exist only one image in the database. Currently I am doing this with two queries. Is there any way to do this with a single query?

I need something like

```
select image from table where if exists more than 1 then select 'non-featured' else select 'featured'
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work yourself around by using the group function `max()`. This function should always return you just 1 image, if it can find it. Otherwise it will return `null`. Then use the function `ifnull()` to get your default image.

```
select ifnull(max(image),'default_image.jpg') from table
```

Comment: +1 I just wanted to add an answer with `COUNT()` and `if`, but this is much cleaner and better, guess you can also learn if you want to answer Questions :D

Comment: thank you for the answer. But i cant get how i will add it with this query `SELECT
 image_name
FROM
 image_details
JOIN product ON image_details.id_fk = product.id
WHERE
 product.p_name = 'product'
AND image_details.featured = "non_featured"
AND image_details.image_status = 'active'`

Comment: i need to get if there exists non_featured images, otherwise select the featured images. Thank you

Comment: @Arun You just put `ifnull(max(image_name), 'default_image.jpg')` in stead of `image_name` in your query.

Comment: @Arun Did you change your question in the grace period? You were talking about getting the default image if there are no images.